# How to suppress Jackson type information of nested collections?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I add type information to JSON using JsonTypeInfo.As.Property with the typeProperty "@class". To suppress getting type information for collection types i have overridden the 'useForType' method on the DefaultTypeResolverBuilder. This works fine for collections containing simple objects. However, when collections are nested, the type information for the nested collection is added by Jackson. 
The following code illustrates the behavior:

```java
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper
        .setDefaultTyping(new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL) {
          {
            init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
            inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
            typeProperty("@class");
          }

          @Override
          public boolean useForType(final JavaType type) {
            return !type.isContainerType() && super.useForType(type);
          }
        });

    final Collection<String> simpleCollection = new HashSet<>();
    simpleCollection.add("simpleCollectionEntry");
    final Collection<Collection<String>> nestedCollection = new HashSet<>();
    final Map<String, Collection<String>> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
    final Set<String> innerCollection = new HashSet<>();
    innerCollection.add("collectionEntry");
    nestedCollection.add(innerCollection);
    nestedMap.put("mapKey", innerCollection);

    final String jsonSimpleCollection = objectMapper
        .writeValueAsString(simpleCollection);
    final String jsonNestedCollection = objectMapper
        .writeValueAsString(nestedCollection);
    final String jsonNestedMap = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(nestedMap);
```

This results in the following output:

```
["simpleCollectionEntry"]
[["java.util.HashSet",["collectionEntry"]]]
{"mapKey":["java.util.HashSet",["collectionEntry"]]}
```

As you can see, the most outer collection is not enriched with type information, whereas type information is added to all inner collections (the collection type does not seem to matter here). How can i configure Jackson to suppress the type information also for inner collections (without skipping to add type information at all)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer...

I added a sysout:

```
  @Override
  public boolean useForType(final JavaType type)
  {
    System.out.println("type :: " + type);
    return !type.isContainerType() && super.useForType(type);
  }
```

And I see this in the console

type :: [collection type; class java.util.HashSet, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]

Looks like the type resolver isn't resolving the type of the content. Seems like a bug in Jackson, and not the config - but I don't have time to confirm that.